# Access YouTrack through path instead of port

Tags: youtrack

Is it possible, without the use of Apache httpd redirects, to install or access YouTrack via a path-like URL? There doesn't seem to be an option for it that I can see.

For instance, instead of `example.com:7777`, you access it via `example.com/youtrack`.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy youtrack.war (this is true for any .war in fact) into a servlet container (Apache Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). By default, the application will be accessible under /youtrack context. You then have to make your servlet container listen on port 80 (please refer to servlet container documentation for details), which will mean that YouTrack is at example.com/youtrack (port 80 is default and thus can be ommited).

Comment: Won't that then mean `httpd` won't be running on port 80?

Comment: No, it won't. Your servlet container will be running on port 80.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help I appreciate it. The problem is httpd needs to be running on port 80.

Comment: Sorry, did not get this point from the very beginning. I'm not an expert in this domain, but seems httpd documentation gives some insights on this starting from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html page.